# React-Native: ERROR: requires JDK11 or higher. Incompatible major version detected: '8'

Tags: javascript, react-native

after running npm install and trying to build my app I get the following error:

```
**************************************************************************************************************



ERROR: requires JDK11 or higher.
Incompatible major version detected: '8'



**************************************************************************************************************






FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kirebyte/using-homebrew-to-install-java-jdk11-on-macos-2021-4a90aa276f1c

Comment: I 'm on Windows

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)

If you already have it, then you might need to review your environmental variables to make sure they are pointing to the right version.

Answer (score 2):

WORKS ON WINDOWS!

First Step you should install https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

make sure you install it on the same folder as where the OpenJDK's  installed before, mine installed on C:\Program Files\OpenJDK, you can check it on the next step.

Then go search Edit the system environment variables [Edit the system environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCrde.png)

Click On Environment Variables
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXgHJ.png)

then change the JAVA_HOME Value location to your JDK 11's Folder you installed before
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOhei.png)

Save it and restart you PC